# updating to newest ubuntu has made it so I can't access mysql...what do I do?

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, ubuntu

I updated to the latest ubuntu distribution and now I can't access my mysql databases!  I used to log in with root without a password, and now when I try to log in I don't have access because I don't know the password.

There are a lot of questions that are similar to this online.  I followed a few of them and the furthest I get is this error:

> (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

I tried to follow */var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock* and **I don't have a mysqld folder**.

So I imagine that's a problem. **Other questions I've seen on here point to** */etc/mysql/...mysql.cnf.*

I have that file but the file doesn't contain anything about a socket.

I'm totally at a loss for how I get access to my databases that I've built!  Please help!  What should I do?

Comment: can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

From terminal:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Error show that the mysql server is not running on your ubuntu machine.

Comment: I just got this message when I entered that:  "Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found."